# importing multipage TIFF image one page at a time

Tags: image, matlab, multidimensional-array, tiff, imread

I have some multipage TIFF images each >4 GB in size. My pc cannot handle the import with [`imread`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#btv1pto-1_1), so I want to import one page at a time using a loop, do what I want with it, and clear the memory at each step.
I red [this post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/04/02/matlab-r2009a-imread-and-multipage-tiffs/) about the possibility to do this. Anyway, I seem not to be able to do what I want, as when I use `info=imfinfo('my_image.tif')`, and then `numel(info)` (as suggested in the post I linked), this last command is supposed to tell me the number of pages in my multipage TIFF, but it outputs just 1. I suppose this has to do with the way I created the images: I used GRASS GIS (combining the [`i.group`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/i.group.html) and [`r.out.gdal`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.out.gdal.html) functions).

Moreover, the information I get from `imfinfo` shows the number of pages (720) into different voices:

1. `BitsPerSample` (which is `1x720 double`)
2. `SamplesPerPixel` (which is `720`)
3. `MaxSampleValue` and `MinSampleValue` (both are `1x720 double`)
4. `SampleFormat` (which is `1x720 cell`)

**EDIT 1**

I forgot to mention that my code is (just like the link):

```
fname = 'my_file_with_lots_of_images.tif';
info = imfinfo(fname);
num_images = numel(info);
for k = 1:num_images
    A = imread(fname, k, 'Info', info);
    % ... Do something with image A ...
    clear A
end
```

When I run it MATLAB gets stucked. I also tried setting `k = 1:2` to test the import of two pages, but the program still gets stucked and I suppos it is not importing only one page but rather all of them at the same time. The image size is 1677x927x720.

Comment: Maybe try using `pdfimages` - a part of the Poppler package.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Matlab has issues with releasing memory, and it also seem to depend on the operating system you area using ([see here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297824)).

I would set a breakpoint at the end of the loop, so you can check after one iteration if only image has been imported in the debugger. Also, if you [check for memory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html) right after your clear call, you might get an idea what is going on.

Also noteworthy might be to try other import functions such as [tiffread2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10298-tiffread2-m) which is optimized for tiff stacks and works well for me, but my stacks are less than 1GB.